# Помогите разобраться с циклом, Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, for

Написал класс извлечения данных из БД, и в ходе его выполнения я получаю данные в Json и соответственно надо извлечь и занести в массив для чего я использую следующий код:

```
    try {
        val json_data = JSONObject(result)
        var d : Array<String> = arrayOf()
        for (i in 1..json_data.length())
        {
            d[i] = json_data.getString("login$i")
        }
        Log.e("pass 3", "Успешно")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString())
    }
```

и в строчке : `d[i] = json_data.getString("login$i")`

я получаю ошибку:`E/Fail 3: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1`

И я никак не могу понять откуда она берётся чего я только не делал, индексы менял и при присвоении переменной массиву и в цикле и пытался по другому определять сам массив, она постоянно вылезает, никак не могу понять где он там вылезает за пределы.

Comment: А у вас массив d какой длины?

Comment: вот объявление `var d : Array<String> = arrayOf()` когда смотрел тему массивов на котлине я там не видел чтобы заранее объявляли размерность массива, но не исключаю конечно что я мог с этим сильно накосячить. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно если знаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё разобрался, оказывается Kotlin не так прост со своими массивами как в других языках с которыми я сталкивался. Для тех кто будет интересоваться этим же вопросом:

Правильная конструкция объявления массива : `var masname = Array<тип данных массива>(size,{значения которыми будет заполнен массив})`

Для примера: `var login2 = Array<String>(5,{"0"})`

Comment: Не совсем так. {"0"} - это лямбда функция, которая может возвращать разные значения на разные индексы массива. Массиву обязательно надо указать размерность, он не может динамически менять длинну. Нужна динамическая длинна - используйте ArrayList. И у вас массив перебирается по рэнжу 1..json_data.length(), это даст выход за границы элемента. Элементы массива начинаются с 0, и перебирать надо 0 until json_data.length() (то есть от 0 до длина-1)

Comment: Да, спасибо за пояснение, в следствие дальнейшей своей работы над проектом, я это тоже выяснил опытным путём так сказать.